# Calculating difference between two pandas dataframes with same columns and some mismatching rows

Tags: python, pandas

df1

```
fileName     obj1   obj2   obj3   obj4
file_01.jpg  1      1      1
file_02.jpg         1      1
file_03.jpg  1      2             1
```

df2

```
fileName     obj1   obj2   obj3   obj4
file_01.jpg  1             2
file_02.jpg         1      1
file_04.jpg         3      1      2
```

Say I have two pandas DataFrames like above, **question:** how can I calculate the difference between te two to get a final DataFrame like below?

**Expected output**
resultdf

```
fileName     obj1   obj2   obj3   obj4
file_01.jpg  0      1      -1      0
file_02.jpg  0      0      0      0
file_03.jpg  1      2      0      1      
file_04.jpg  0      -3     -1     -2
```

**What I've already tried** : I reached the result by merging the two DataFrames together, and then calculating the difference between two columns. Raising this question in SO to see if there is any other efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find a groupby subtract so I multiplied your second df by -1 so `sum` could product the desired result

```
obj_cols = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4']
df2[obj_cols] *= -1

pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['fileName'], as_index=False).sum()

      fileName  obj1  obj2  obj3  obj4
0  file_01.jpg     0     1    -1     0
1  file_02.jpg     0     0     0     0
2  file_03.jpg     1     2     0     1
3  file_04.jpg     0    -3    -1    -2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close.  I would just:

- do an outer join
- groupby filename with sum
- reset index

Like:

```
In [25]: df1                                                                    
Out[25]: 
   a  value
0  2     33
1  3     10
2  5      2

In [26]: df2                                                                    
Out[26]: 
   a  value
0  1     -1
1  3      2
2  5    -50

In [27]: df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')                                      

In [28]: df3                                                                    
Out[28]: 
   a  value
0  2     33
1  3     10
2  5      2
3  1     -1
4  3      2
5  5    -50

In [29]: df3.groupby('a').sum().reset_index()                                   
Out[29]: 
   a  value
0  1     -1
1  2     33
2  3     12
3  5    -48
```

Comment: thanks Jeff! I am only looking for other ways to achieve the results, and this is helpful!